# Can't push to GitHub because of a large file I already deleted

Tags: git, github

I just started using git and GitHub.  I tried to push a large file and got an error message.  So, I deleted the file but I'm still getting the same error message even though the file doesn't exist.

I read other posts suggesting to use the git filter-branch command shown in the first line of the below code section.

I tried putting in the directory and file name into the file/dir part of the command and executed the command without error.  But, I'm still getting the same error.  I haven't been able to find any other resolution than this.  It seems to work for others.  I don't understand why it isn't working for me.

```
#command that works for others
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <file/dir>' HEAD

MAC OS Terminal
#I enter & execute command
 $git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <pagerank>' HEAD
Rewrite 02d20ace05b2327ae69832d94d8e22f222cd3700 (1/7) (0 seconds passed, remaining 0 predicted)    /usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: eval: line 425: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/usr/local/git/libexec/git-core/git-filter-branch: eval: line 425: `git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <pagerank>'
index filter failed: git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <pagerank>

#git status and push
$git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 4 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Robs-MacBook-Pro:Git_repo 

$ Git push -u origin master
Enumerating objects: 27, done.
Counting objects: 100% (27/27), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done.
Writing objects: 100% (26/26), 156.52 MiB | 6.30 MiB/s, done.
Total 26 (delta 3), reused 1 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 475810e9f982012443b42937b517e5db
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Pagerank/spider.sqlite is 784.58 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/resonates7/Repo_1.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/resonates7/Repo_1.git'
```

I want to understand what's happening so I can debug future issues and successfully push my files to github.  I don't really need to save large files there. Thanks in advance for the help from all you really smart people.

Comment: Did you commit the delete?

Comment: *index filter failed: git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <pagerank>* What is `<pagerank>`?

Comment: Are you including literal `<` and `>` in your command? Those indicate a value to be replaced. If your file is called `pagerank` you should use `pagerank` not `<pagerank>`.